# List of dicts - add key-values for items with same value for another key-value

Tags: python

with a list of dict like below

```
[{'Main ID': 0, 'Sub IDs': [0]}, {'Main ID': 0, 'Sub IDs': [3]}, {'Main ID': 2, 'Sub IDs': [3]}]
```

I need to compress this to the below format

```
[{'Main ID': 0, 'Sub IDs': [0,3]}, {'Main ID': 2, 'Sub IDs': [3]}]
```

That is add the lists containing `Sub IDs` for the same `Main ID` - here item0 and item1 has the same value for `Main ID`.

What would be the pythonic way to achieve this - is there a way with list comprehension ?

Comment: Are the `'Main ID'` values always in order, like in your example?

Comment: no, cannot be guaranteed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a dictionary to store a set of sub ids for each main id and iterate the list. I'm assuming sub ids are unique? Then create a new list with the dictionary at the end.

```
lst = [{'Main ID': 0, 'Sub IDs': [0]}, {'Main ID': 0, 'Sub IDs': [3]}, {'Main ID': 2, 'Sub IDs': [3]}]
d = {}
for dd in lst:
    d.setdefault(dd['Main ID'], set()).update(dd['Sub IDs'])

newlst = [{'Main ID':k, 'Sub IDs':list(v)} for k,v in d.items()]
print(newlst)
```

Output:

```
>>>[{'Main ID': 0, 'Sub IDs': [0, 3]}, {'Main ID': 2, 'Sub IDs': [3]}]
```

Answer (score 2):

The first step is to get a `set` of all different `'Main ID'`s. We can also immediately `sum` up each one's lists of `'Sub IDs'`, since we now conveniently have grouped them together.

```
l = [{'Main ID': 0, 'Sub IDs': [0]}, {'Main ID': 0, 'Sub IDs': [3]}, {'Main ID': 2, 'Sub IDs': [3]}]

for key in set(key['Main ID'] for key in l):
    print (key, end=': ')
    print (sum([value['Sub IDs'] for value in l if value['Main ID'] == key],[]))
```

```
0: [0, 3]
2: [3]
```

That works nicely, and you're actually already done here! This result could be used as a simple list of lists. But you want to reconstruct the dictionary. The original key names are lost so we insert them again, making it a dictionary again.

```
for key in set(key['Main ID'] for key in l):
    print ({'Main ID':key, 'Sub IDs':sum([value['Sub IDs'] for value in l if value['Main ID'] == key],[])})
```

```
{'Main ID': 0, 'Sub IDs': [0, 3]}
{'Main ID': 2, 'Sub IDs': [3]}
```

Since this is surrounded by a simple `for` loop over a set, we can make it a full list comprehension by wrapping this `for` back into a list, by moving the `set` loop to the end of what we already have:

```
print ([{'Main ID':key, 'Sub IDs':sum([value['Sub IDs'] for value in l if value['Main ID'] == key],[])} for key in set(key['Main ID'] for key in l)])
```

which is a one-line for this

```
print (
    [
        {'Main ID':key,
         'Sub IDs':sum(
                [
                    value['Sub IDs'] for value in l if value['Main ID'] == key
                ], []
            )
         } for key in
         set(
                key['Main ID'] for key in l
            )
    ] )
```

and with the desired result

```
[{'Main ID': 0, 'Sub IDs': [0, 3]}, {'Main ID': 2, 'Sub IDs': [3]}]
```