# Merge list of dictionaries by certain key and append distinct values to list

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Given a list of dictionaries:

```
list_of_dicts = [
    {"docId": 1, "attr1": 1, "attr2": "red"},
    {"docId": 1, "attr1": 1, "attr2": "blue"},
    {"docId": 2, "attr1": 2, "attr2": "purple"}
]
```

I want to get:

```
result = [
    {"docId": 1, "attr1": 1, "attr2": ["red", "blue"]},
    {"docId": 2, "attr1": 2, "attr2": ["purple"]}  # list of 1 just for consistency's sake
]
```

Essentially I want to merge dictionaries from a list based on their "docId", and if "attr2" has unique values, put them into a list in the new dictionary. It is only "attr2" that I want to convert to a list of unique values. The other attributes like "attr1" will always be the same.

Currently I'm doing something along the lines of:

```
result = []
for doc in list_of_dicts:
    if result != []:
        for res in result:
            if doc["docId"] == res["docId"]:
                if doc.get("attr2") not in res.get("attr2"):
                    res["attr2"].append(doc["attr2"])
                else:
                    result.append(
                        {
                            "docId": doc["docId"],
                            "attr1": doc["attr1"],
                            "attr2": [doc["attr2"]]
                        }
                    )
    else:
        result.append(
            {"docId": doc["docId"], "attr1": doc["attr1"], "attr2": [doc["attr2"]]}
        )
```

Then finally filtering the final result for unique dictionaries. This feels rather inefficient and I was wondering if there's a more Pythonic way to do things; maybe with list comprehensions and fewer if-else conditions.

Comment: yes, you can decrease the number of if-else. Try using a set for att2 which you can convert to list later. And rather than iterating list, again and again, maintain a dict with docId as key for faster retrieval.

Comment: Duplicate here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60134299/list-of-dicts-add-key-values-for-items-with-same-value-for-another-key-value#60134299

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `groupby` from the `itertools` module.

```
from itertools import groupby

# Group by docId and attr1
def f(d):
    return d['docId'], d['attr1']

# x is a docId
# y is an attr1
# z is an iterator of elements from list_of_dicts that have the same
#  docId and attr1 value.
result = [{
            'docId': x,
            'attr1': y,
            'attr2': [d['attr2'] for d in z]
          }
          for (x,y), z in groupby(sorted(list_of_dicts, key=f), f)]
```

Comment: Is there some way to access the other attributes besides from the return of the f() function? Essentially the docId is the unique identifier, and the list of attributes is longer. I'm not sure typing out the list of other attributes in the return is the best. This is what I was trying but I would lose the first element of the "attr2" list. 
```
result = [
    {
        "docId": x,
        "attr1": d["attr1"],
        "attr2": [d["attr2"] for d in z],
    }
    for x, z in groupby(sorted(list_of_dicts, key=lambda x: x["docId"]), lambda x: x["docId"]) for d in z 
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another approach. Not as elegant as chepner's answer ;-) but just in case you don't want to use `itertools`.

```
result = [list_of_dicts[0]]

for dict_ in list_of_dicts:
    for result_dict in result:
        if result_dict.get("docId") == dict_["docId"]:
            try:
                result_dict["attr2"].append(dict_["attr2"])
            except AttributeError:
                result_dict["attr2"] = [result_dict["attr2"]]
        else:
            temp_dict = dict(dict_)
            result.append(temp_dict)
```

**Output**

```
[
    {'docId': 1, 'attr1': 1, 'attr2': ['red', 'blue']},
    {'docId': 2, 'attr1': 2, 'attr2': ['purple']}
]
```